# Why does it look like multiple processes are being used when only 1 process is specified?

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

Please forgive me as I'm new to using the multiprocessing library in python and new to testing multiprocess/multi-threaded projects.

In some legacy code, someone created a pool of processes to execute multiple processes in parallel.  I'm trying to debug the code by making the pool only have 1 process but the output looks like it's still using multiple processes.

Below is some sanitized example code.  Hopefully I included all the important elements to demo what I'm experiencing.

```
def myTestFunc():
   pool = multiprocessing.Pool(1)  # should only use 1 process
   for i in someListOfNames:
      pool.apply_async(method1, args=(listA))

def method1(listA):
   for i in listA:
      print "this is the value of i: " + i
      sys.stdout.flush()
```

What is happening is since I expect there should only be 1 process in the pool, I shouldn't have any output collision.  What I see sometimes in the log msgs is this:

```
this is the value of i: Alpha
this is the value of i: Bravo
this is the this is the value of i: Mike   # seems like 2 things trying to write at the same time
```

The two things writing at the same time seems to appear closer to the bottom of my debug log, rather than the top, which means the longer I run, the more likely I get these msgs overwriting each other.  I haven't tested with a shorter list yet though.

I realize testing multi-process/multi-threaded programs is difficult but in this case, I think I've restricted it such that it should be a lot easier than normal to test.  I'm confused why this is happening b/c

1. I set the pool to have only 1 process
2. (I think) I force the process to flush its write buffer so it should be writing w/o waiting/queuing and getting this situation.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

Comment: When I ran your code (adding in the lists) it printed the output you would expect... is there something you're not showing?

Comment: @PeterM.Elias, Thanks for looking and trying to help me. I don't think I can post the full functions publicly =( I tried to put what I thought was important, which was the pool.apply_async() and the 2nd method being called, which is where i was putting my print statements to try to debug things.  I can see if I can add anymore elements/info to the question but I don't know how much more I can add.  Hopefully the things I mentioned with the Pool(1) and apply_async is enough to explain what I'm seeing.

Comment: I definitely understand privacy so no worries.  Just so you know, I literally copied and pasted the code you provided, made up listA and someListOfNames and the output was identical to single-threaded output of the same operations. This leads me to believe that whatever is causing your problem is not going to be "debuggable" using the code you have provided.

Comment: @PeterM.Elias, I appreciate your time  =)  Time to bash my head against the wall some more.  I definitely will post an update if something hits me of either a) why this is occurring or b) providing more info for ppl to look at to help me